# Activate js when snowing in users location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, weather-api

So I have js that I want to only activate if it is snowing in the users area.

Here is a JSFiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/znb2zskt/)

```
<h1 onclick="snowStorm.toggleSnow();">
text
</h1>

<script src="https://web.archive.org/web/20161109225359/http://live.superedu.ml/snow.js"></script>
<script>
snowStorm.followMouse = false;
    snowStorm.freezeOnBlur = true;
    snowStorm.autoStart = false;

</script>
```

if you click test it activates snow.
how would I make this to activate the snow when it is snowing where the user is. thank you

Comment: If you are wondering why I am using webarchive its because i am using my own modified code

Comment: you'd have to look out their window to see if it's snowing I guess

Comment: Are you using any kind of weather API? You could get user data from the area they are located in and fire an event to start the snow if certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to know if it's snowing or not at the user's location. So the very first thing you need to know is where they are. For this you use an IP geolocation service. Google it. One of them is https://freegeoip.net/

Next you need to ask a weather service about the weather.
Look into https://darksky.net/dev/docs/forecast

In order to ask something to a service like DarkSky API you will need to tell them the location you are interested in for the forecast, which is where you use the location coordinates you received from the geolocation service above.

You will then receive a response "object" from the DarkSky API, which will contain a bunch of information, amongst which the precipitation info as described below:

> `precipType` *optional*
>   The type of precipitation occurring at the given time. If defined, this property will have one of the following values: `"rain"`, `"snow"`, or `"sleet"` (which refers to each of freezing rain, ice pellets, and `“wintery mix”`). (If `precipIntensity` is zero, then this property will not be defined.)
>   https://darksky.net/dev/docs/response

After which you can code something along the lines of

```
if (data.precipType === 'snow') { // do something }
```

Overall, it goes like this:

1. Send request to GeoIP (where is ip 8.8.8.8 ?)
2. Receive response from GeoIP (it's at lat:1.2345 lon:1.432)
3. Send request to DarkSky (what's the weather today at lat:1.2345 lon:1.432 ?)
4. Receive response from DarkSky (snow!)
5. … do stuff …

### How

In order to succeed at this exercise, you will ned to familiarise a bit with basic *asynchronous programming* in JS, and how to send an **AJAX** request, and consume the response you receive.

In short you need to learn how to write code that is able to start function B only after function A is done (after an unknown amount of time, like when requesting over the net)

So things will look more like this:

```
1. Send request to GeoIP (where is ip 8.8.8.8 ?)
  2. Receive response from GeoIP (it's at lat:1.2345 lon:1.432)
    3. Send request to DarkSky (what's the weather today at lat:1.2345 lon:1.432 ?)
      4. Receive response from DarkSky (snow!)
        5. … do stuff …
```

Good keywords to search for this are jQuery AJAX, callbacks, and a tad more advanced, Promises. But start with the first two.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you this will help alot